# What is $\mathbb{P}(X<Y\mid X+Y=z)$ where $X,Y$ are i.i.d exponential?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Let $X\perp Y\sim Exp(\frac{1}{5})$, find:

a) the density of $X$ conditioned to the event $X+Y=z$.

b) the probability $\mathbb{P}(X<Y\mid X+Y=z)$.

---

For a) we have $X\mid Z\sim U(0,z)\Rightarrow f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{z}\mathbb{1}_{[0,z]}(x)$.

For b) i have a doubt… Can i write as follows?

> $\mathbb{P}(X<Y\mid X+Y=z)=\mathbb{P}(X<\frac{z}{2}\mid Y=z-x)=\int_{0}^{\frac{z}{2}}[\int_{0}^{z}\frac{1}{5z}e^{-\frac{x}{5}}dz]dx$

Thanks in advance for any clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well then $X$ and $Y$ are iid random variables with exponential distribution (please correct me if I am wrong).

Then by symmetry it is immediate that: $$P(X<Y\mid X+Y=z)=P(Y<X\mid X+Y=z)$$Moreover it is evident that: $$P(X=Y\mid X+Y=z)=0$$ so that we can conclude that:$$P(X<Y\mid X+Y=z)=0.5$$

Comment: You understood correctly. Thanks!